# A variable that put in bracket of data table just comes out as it is. (R language)

Tags: r

I am using R data table packages. I just want to access specific column of data table using variable.
But, When I put variable in bracket of data table, a variable just comes out as it is. not data table.

for example,

```
df <- matrix(1:12,nrow=4,ncol=3)
df <- as.data.table(df)
colnames(df) <- c("A","B","C")
list <- c("A","B","C")
df[,"C"]
```

The result of above code is just "C" not (9, 10, 11, 12).
And other result that I tried to figure out this problem are below.

`df[,list[3]]`

> [1] "C"

`df[,"C"]`

> C
>
> 1:  9
>
> 2: 10
>
> 3: 11
>
> 4: 12

`list[3] == "C"`

> [1] TRUE

Why does this problem happen? How do I get specific column from data table using variable?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of data.table are you using? They changed that a while ago (apparently [v1.9.8](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md)).

For your version, try `with = FALSE`. From `help(data.table)`:

> By default with=TRUE and j is evaluated within the frame of x; column
>   names can be used as variables. In case of overlapping variables names
>   inside dataset and in parent scope you can use double dot prefix
>   ..cols to explicitly refer to 'cols variable parent scope and not from
>   your dataset.
>
> When j is a character vector of column names, a numeric vector of
>   column positions to select or of the form startcol:endcol, and the
>   value returned is always a data.table. with=FALSE is not necessary
>   anymore to select columns dynamically.

```
library(data.table)
df[,"C",with=FALSE]
    C
1:  9
2: 10
3: 11
4: 12
```

This also works.

```
df[,list[3],with=FALSE]
    C
1:  9
2: 10
3: 11
4: 12
```

The more data.table way to do it would be `C` without quotes.

```
df[,C]
[1]  9 10 11 12
```

You might wonder why `df[,"C"]` returns a `data.table`, but `df[,C]` returns a vector. And that, I would argue is a good question. I guess because `df[,"C"]` is similar to how one would subset a `data.frame` which would also return a `data.frame`.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
data.table_1.12.8
```

Comment: I am using 1.10.0 version of data.table. I can solve it thanks to you.